# Wordpress admin is incredibly slow

Tags: php, wp-admin

I built a WordPress site for a client a couple of years ago and over the course of those years, they've accumulated 21,000+ articles, have 30,000-50,000 views per day, and have 300+ active writers, editors and admins. So, obviously, the back-end is slow... but I still feel like it's inordinately slow most of the time - typically > 30 seconds.

Steps I've taken so far to speed up the site/admin:

1. limit revisions to 7 per post and delete old ones.
2. Increase the memory limit to 96mb
3. This site is load balanced between three high performance cloud servers and tied into a cloud database.

Things I've thought of to help:

1. Offload the post editing to a separate, private site and send posts from that site to the live site with the API.
2. Find a different way to manage post custom fields (currently using Advanced Custom Fields and, due to the nature of the site, there are quite a few per post).

I can't turn off plugins to test because this is a very busy and active site. I tried using the debug mode and using firefox developer tools Network tab to try to identify slow culprits... but everything is slow - not just one thing. Typically, the slowest thing to load is the script itself.

Any help would be much appreciated as the client is getting frustrated by a slow back-end and is more frequently running into "Are you sure you want to do this?" errors or blank screens and losing work.

Comment: This question is too broad and too localized to answer adequately. But as an admin for a blog with comparable weight I can say that it needn't be like this. The solution migh lay in WP settings, but you may also simply need a new server. Have you contacted your hosting party to ask what they see in terms of server load?

Comment: It can be so many things that it's impossible for us to know. I believe the only way to test such a busy site is to have a local copy. You can run some [tests](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) and study the theme code and each plugin individually. Also, it's known that some high performance hostings save resources by slowing down the admin area deliberately.

Comment: @cjbj, Yes, I have been in contact with the hosting team as well as viewing the server analytics they offer. I also have new relic installed on the server. None of the sources indicate irregular traffic or a specific source of a high load - just constant use and lots of database queries from WordPress. We have had as many as 5 servers to balance the load - but even during that time, the admin was still slow.

Comment: @LuisSanz I do have a QA environment - but I cannot mimic the high load on that server. Of note though, on the QA environment (identical plugins, server config and database to the live site), that admin runs fine. The theme is custom built by me to limit impact on the server and database. I will check with the hosting company to see if they might be intentionally slowing down the admin, but I highly doubt that in this case.

Comment: @JoshChristopherson Query Monitor is a good plugin to test for performance issues, and slow queries, but we can't help you if all there is to go on is that it's slow. If your site is slow it's because you're doing too much, you need to look at what you're doing, maybe it's 1 or 2 very expensive things, or 200 small things that add up, who knows? Find out exactly what is slow first. Looking at your comments you might want to look at uncached functions, try running the VIP Scanner tool on your sites codebase

Comment: @TomJNowell Thank you - Query monitor was the answer. I was able to identify exactly what was the problem. Now I just have to find a way to solve it. I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

A dev version clearly needs to be created. Resolving this will take time. You will need debug and the ability to experiment with disabling plugins.

Chances are, the slowness is caused from a bad query with a plugin. Or too many scripts. Also, 100mb of memory is far inadequate for a site with that much traffic. For me, Id go minimum 500, depending on what plugins you use.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I do have an identical dev/QA version - but alas, I cannot replicate the high traffic load and thus, the QA environment admin runs perfectly. Thanks for the suggestion about memory though. Are you referring to the PHP memory limit or the server memory? The server has over 8gb of memory if I remember right. The PHP memory limit was what I increased to 96mb.